# Need macro to run on all cells (with String) in column D

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub arranges()

Dim str As String
str = ActiveCell.Value

ActiveCell.Value = Left(str, 3) & "/" & Mid(str, 4, 2) & "R" & Mid(str, 6, 2) _


End Sub
```

Column D - Data

```
2755520
1956016
2454518
2256016
1856014
```

The end result is: `275/55R20` ---> the result would be for all cells in column D. the Macro adds "/" & "R" at the specific locations in the string I need to finalize the data.

Comment: And what is the expected output?

Comment: can you provide more details about code

Comment: The end result is:  275/55R20 ---> the result would be for all cells in column D.  the Macro adds "/" & "R" at the specific locations in the string I need to finalize the data.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding what you are looking for correctly, this would hit every cell in column D. If you want to skip the first row, put `If cell.row <> 1 Then` before `cell.Value = ...`.

```
Sub arranges()
Dim cell As Range, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

For Each cell In ws.Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    cell.Value = Left(cell.Text, 3) & "/" & Mid(cell.Text, 4, 2) & "R" & Mid(cell.Text, 6, 2)
Next cell

End Sub
```